# Adjust colorbox size with html5 video

Tags: jquery, html5-video, colorbox

I'm embedding a video in a colorbox, but I use `$.colorbox()` since the video won't be started by a lin click.

Here is a snippet : http://jsfiddle.net/xavier_seignard/48Zhz/

I do not succed at sizing the colorbox accordingly with the video size so there is no scroll.

Any idea?

Regards,

Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally switched to http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/, much better!